# Example of a deterministic algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, deterministic

Good evening I was wondering if someone could please provide me with a simple pseudocode example of a deterministic algorithm... I will greatly appreciate it and surely give you points!!. thanks

Answer (score 5):

To me, "deterministic" could mean many things:

- Given the same input, produces the same output every time.
- Given the same input, takes the same amount of time/memory/resources every time it is run.
- Problems of complexity class `P` that can be solved in polynomial time by a deterministic computer, as opposed to problems of complexity class `NP` which can be only solved in polynomial time using a *non-deterministic computer*.

Which of these do you mean?

The most simple deterministic algorithm is this [random number generator](http://xkcd.com/221/).

```
def random():
    return 4 #chosen by fair dice roll, guaranteed to be random
```

It gives the same output every time, exhibits known `O(1)` time and resource usage, and executes in `PTIME` on any computer.

Answer (score 1):

A deterministic algorithm is simply an algorithm that has a predefined output. For instance if you are sorting elements that are strictly ordered(no equal elements) the output is well defined and so the algorithm is deterministic.

In fact most of the computer algorithms are deterministic. Undeterminism usually apears when you have some parallelization or some equal elements that are only equal according to some non-full criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really mean DETERMINISTIC and not NONdeterministic, I mean pretty much anything you see in any tutorial / guide / start book is deterministic, e.g.

```
for i from 1 to 9 
    print i
```

will always print 123456789

Answer (score 0):

Here's pseudo code for a deterministic algorithm that checks whether a given number is odd:

```
function is_odd(n):
    if n mod 2 = 1
    then return true
    else return false
```

Answer (score 0):

deterministic algorithm is an algorithm which, in informal terms, behaves predictably. Given a particular input, it will always produce the same output

```
public struct Point {
   public int x;
   public int y; 

   //other methods

   public override int GetHashCode() {
      return x ^ y;
   }
}

Point P=new Point();
p.x=6;
p.y=3;
int res= p.GetHashCode();
```